# Bootstrap's "data-offset" jumps after scroll - div spacer?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstraps data-spy and data-offset to keep part of the sites header at the top after scroll down the page. The problem is, after reaching the data offset point and becomes "affixed" to the top it seems like the page jumps. I know its not actually jumping, the rest of the page content is simply behind the fixed nav. I have tried to add a div spacer for the height of the part of the nav that sticks, however cant implement this bit so it appears at the same time of the data-offset.

```
            <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="96" id="nav">
```

Take a look at my example... scroll slowly and you will notice content seems to be behind the fixed header. https://googledrive.com/host/0B8UWGEiox1HOOUJhU0xndzBBZ00/test_20062013_Rudge.html

Comment: So are you saying you want to see the text behind the navbar when you scroll down?

Comment: when the top of the screen hits the purple bar you lose the next 76px underneath (the thumbnails). It needs to work more like this http://happycog.com/ they have a div spacer in place but for he life of me cant figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `<div id="nav" ...>` "disappears" when it is fixed. When the element changes position from static to fixed, then it does not takes the space in your layout anymore. As the result everything below moves up for the same distance as the height of the fixed element. Standard solution is to contain the element in yet another `<div id="nav-wrapper">` with the height exactly the same as affixed, so when `<div id="nav" ...>` disappears `nav-wrapper` does not change the size.

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
  <div id="nav" ...>
    ...
  </div>
</div>

#nav-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}
```

In case you cannot predict the height of the nav-bar, use the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
```